# Android studio doesn't show my Android phone

Tags: android

I have just started android app development. But I have been facing an issue since the beginning. I am trying to connect my Android 4.4 powered Intex Aqua Star II with Android Studio. But it's not recognizing my device. Infact, it is displaying a random emulator in the list which I can't use. 
I can connect all other devices but this. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: SDK Manager -> Download Google USB Driver if you have not done so already

Comment: Is USB debugging ON in your device?

Comment: yes, USB debugging is ON.

Comment: Did you allow the access? There should be a popup when connecting.

Comment: Try to install your phone driver from official website ,, if not working install `kies` program , this works for me

Comment: Download the Samsung USB Driver. It works with most of strange devices. After you installed it, go to Device Manager and find your phone which is shown with big yellow warning. Right click to it and try to install drivers with list and choose Samsung Composite Driver"

Comment: If you not get the allow access popup then goto the Developer option inside settings and click on "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" and click "OK" button and try again to connect the USB.

Comment: First of all, when I connect USB, following options are shown : 1. USB Storage   2. USB tetheriing   3. MTP    4. PTP     5. USB virtual drive   6. Charge ONLY.... Which one should I choose?

Comment: I downloaded the Google USB Driver from the SDK manager but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Goto

MyComputer-->RightClick---> Properties-->Device Manager-->In this you will get your android device

Right click on that device-->Select Update Driver Software--> Browse Driver software---> Now browse google usb driver which will be available in your sdk

like C:\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

and select AdbInterface

Comment: it says "windows couldn't find driver for your device"